# Dynamically adding html elements into a cell without using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript. How do I add a dynamically created html element into a dynamically created table cell without using cell.innerhtml attribute?

Comment: You could use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: Why not replace the whole table? Depending on your scenario that could be faster.

Comment: I do not want to use appendChild as that seems to append to the end of the table. I also do not want to replace the whole table. I am inserting the cell somewhere in the middle of the table. For example, I want to insert an "input" element (with specific properties) in a specific cell. I am doing something like this -  var inp = document.createElement('input'); <<some processing on this element>> and then I want to add this input element to a cell.

Comment: Oh my bad, @SimpleJ, actually appendChild works fine! Thanks so much

Comment: Please, add the information you commented above to your questionby [edit]ing it. Also, show us the base code of your current try. Please, read this: [mcve] to receive better answers to your question and not be downvoted. It would be nice also to tell why `innerHTML` is not an option

Answer (score 1):

Hi just use the js code like below

```
var para = document.createElement("p");  
var node = document.createTextNode("This is a new paragraph.");
para.appendChild(node);
```

To set attribute for element

```
Para.setAttribute("class", "css");
```

Happy coding:)